# See total downloads of app in Windows Dev Center

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-dev-center

I'm trying to see the total amount of downloads of my app in Windows Dev Center but can only choose last 30 days or 3 months for instant report. I can't click the "Historical" selection in the following image.

[image]

The most intuitive way would be to go to https://dev.windows.com/analytics/reports/acquisitions?productId=myProductIdGoesHere which shows acquisitions. I can change filters but they only filter on OS version and market.

The "download reports" is found in the Analytics menu and has the following URL. 
https://dev.windows.com/analytics/reports/export?productId=9id9id

Comment: i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is here right now. Post any other links if you find any better and I'll make sure they get in the "Marked answer"post.
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9697347-windows-phone-store-should-show-total-number-of-ap

Answer (score 2):

Got the same question and did some research, I haven't found how to get total amount of downloads, but there is a way to see the data for last year, at least.

Near the top of each page (Acquisitions, Reviews, Health and so on), you can expand Page filters to filter all of the data on this page by date range. The default filter is Last 30 days, but you can expand this up to Last 12 months.

So once I selected "Last 12 month", I've got graphs and digits for the last year.

P.S. I was trying to upload images to make it more clear but got a message "You need at least 10 reputation to post images", sorry about that.